# How to use wordpress content class?

Tags: widgets

```
<div class="sidebar_area">
<h4>Sponsor</h4>
<div class="sidebar_content">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">This is new post</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This is new post</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This is new post</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This is new post</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This is new post</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This is new post</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I like to make my widget like this code. But problem is here I can't use widget content like bellow. How can I give sidebar content div with "sidebar_area" class.

```
<div class="sidebar_area">
<h4>Sponsor</h4>
<div class="sidebar_content">
    <!-- content goes here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Should this `<div class="sidebar_area">` be the **sidebar container** or the **widget container**? And what do you mean with _I can't use widget content like below_?

Comment: widget container after title.

Comment: Hm? In your question you seem to be talking about `sidebar_area`, which comes **before** the title. So what is it? If you're looking for help here, you should consider writing more than just a _short message_...

Comment: Sorry, Just a mistake. It should be <div class="sidebar_content">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Sidebar Name',
    'id' => 'sidebar-id',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="sidebar_area">',
    'before_title' => '<h4>',
    'after_title' => '</h4><div class="sidebar_content">',
    'after_widget' => '</div></div>',
));
```

**References:**

- [`register_sidebar`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar)

Comment: It is ok. But problem is here if I don't use title in my sidebar widget than it will not work fine and create another problem.

Comment: Well, that's right. If you don't use titles **at all**, you can just move the second `<div>` into the `before_widget` parameter. If you use titles on some widgets, and **not** on some others, then there's no _easy_ solution.

Comment: Really it is a limitation of WordPress.

Comment: Well, not really. You **can** do this. It's just not done with some parameters. You would have to hook into [`dynamic_sidebar_params`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/widgets.php#L888), then check for your sidebar, and adjust the params according to whether a title is present or not.

Comment: hmm. Can you give me tutorial link about it .

Comment: I inform that I have to use 4 sidebar area one is right sidebar and other three is footer sidebar. I like to use different content class for every sidebar

Comment: Since you define the `div` along with its class for each sidebar, you can give each sidebar an individual widget class. That being said, this comment thread is getting rather long. If you need help with another problem, post a new question. No matter what, this provides a way to achieve what you have asked for.

Comment: Really is it related of my question.

Answer (score 1):

Just register the sidebar and determine what to add before and after widget:

```
register_sidebar( array( 
    'name'          => __('My sidebar', 'cht'),
    'id'            => 'mysidebar',
    'class'         => 'sidebar_area',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="sidebar_content %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => "</div>\n",
    'before_title'  => '<h4>',
    'after_title'   => "</h4>\n"
));
```

Comment: "</div>\n" ??  What is n ?

Comment: UNIX end of a line - just... trust me it should be there.

Comment: How is the answer above better than mine - which BTW was posted 5 minutes earlier than the above one?

Comment: All that `\n` does is format the generated markup, which is pointless. You are _never_ going to edit the generated markup so the only thing that formatting it does is increase the size of the file that has to be transmitted to the browser.